# How to run the process with SYSTEM privileges when a scheduled task is created using AutoIt

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, autoit

I have one task which triggers the exe on system start. Task is created with highest privileges and SYSTEM privileges but actual process runs with user level privileges. How to run the process also with system privileges

```
Local $taskName = 'test1'
_TaskExists($taskName)
If @error = 0 Then
_trace("Task " & $taskName & " exists: updating...")
RunWait("schtasks /DELETE /F /TN " & $taskName, $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /RU SYSTEM /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & 
@ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONSTART /RL HIGHEST ", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
 Else
_trace("Task " & $taskName & " does not exist: creating...")
RunWait("schtasks /CREATE /RU SYSTEM /F /TN " & $taskName & " /TR " & '"' & 
@ScriptFullPath & '"' & " /SC ONSTART /RL HIGHEST ", $WORKING_DIR, @SW_HIDE)
If @error Then
    _error("Task " & $taskName & " was not created successfully: " & @error)
EndIf
EndIf
```

Is there any way that we could run the process also with SYSTEM privileges?

Note: It is a GUI process

Comment: It looks like you simply need to use `schtasks /CREATE /RU SYSTEM /F /TN` and then the rest of your logic just like you have it. So after the `/CREATE` add in `/RU SYSTEM` before the `/F` and then run the logic like that and see if you get the expected result. Tag me back `@RongaliRamunaidu` and let me know if that helps resolve or not.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I have tried what you mentioned. It didn't resolve.Task has system privileges, but process is still created with Administrator privileges.